# DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, I tried the other solutions but not worked

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer, android-coordinatorlayout, drawerlayout

I have a problem with adding a drawer navigation with the bottom navigation, the bottom navigation requires the coordinatorLayout and the drawer navigation requires the drawerLayout, so I tried to nest the CoordinatorLayout inside the DrawerLayout but I'm getting the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:` DrawerLayout must be measured with `MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.` !!

Could someone help in this because I tried many solutions provided on the internet that doesn't work with me!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <!-- -->
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include layout="@layout/activity_navigation_drawer"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="@string/title_break_news" />

    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

    android:id="@+id/drawerNav"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_navigation_drawer"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_navigation_drawer_drawer"/>
```

Comment: You should either be using `BottomNavigation` or `NavigationDrawer`

Comment: I need them both! so?

Comment: @SaranSankaran, why so?

Comment: `bottom navigation requires the coordinatorLayout` - who said so?

Comment: @azizbekian I was telling from a design point of view. Both are navigations and why should there be both bottom navigation and navDrawer at the same time.

Comment: @SaranSankaran I need both of them for different purposes. I have a bottom navigation for one page, also I need a drawer navigation for another options for the whole application